# basic applications of data structure

Tags: c, data-structures

I have to do a project for my college course in data structures using c and was wondering if anyone can tell me any real life uses of data structures so that I can base my project on it.
Please keep in mind that it is only my first year of programming in c so I currently do not have the skills to write very advanced code.

Comment: you better have a research on web and then ask some question which is more specific. There are infinite number of real like uses of data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is your first year of college, I wouldn't go into the depths of datastructures and their uses.

Simplest use of a data structure: A English-to-English Dictionary, which can be built using a Hash Table.

From here, you can go into depths of DS

1. Datastructures in OS design, such as memory manager (Linked List + Hash-Map),
2. BTrees in Database Design
3. Trees in Filesystems
4. Graphs in electronic circuit simulation, AI etc

many many more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, data structures improve the logic or performance of manipulations on your data. To see the latter, you could try the following. Generate a list of a million or more random numbers and try to find one of them in particular.

Try comparing the performance of the following two representations: an array and a sorted [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of real usages of data structures, whether it's in your OS, in Databases, etc.
Think of the case of (not only) MySQL that uses B-Trees to manage records (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [list of data structures from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures). Most of the data structures have real world examples or applications section on their own description page.